# How does one add a computed column to a django model's list page?

Tags: django, templates, view

I have a model,

```
class Thingie(models.Model):
    thingie_name = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    interesting_property = models.BogusField(...)
```

...and in admin.py:

```
class ThingieAdmin(adimn.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('thingie_name', 'interesting_property')
```

When I look at the admin page for this, I see something like the following:

```
Select Thingie to change

Thingie name    | Interesting property
monkey_nuggets  | you really don't want to know
yodeling_yoda   | this is going downhill fast
```

What I'd like is to have a third field here, a generated URL:

```
Thingie name    | ... | For more info...
monkey_nuggets  | ... | http://foo.com/thingie/monkey_nuggets
yodeling_yoda   | ... | http://foo.com/thingie/yodeling_yoda
```

Note that I am NOT looking to send people to the edit page for this property. I just need a way to affect the rendering of the view in such a way that I can insert a custom column that isn't backed by the database, it's just computed based upon one of the other values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a method in your model admin to do this.

```
class ThingieAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('thingie_name', 'interesting_property', 'computed_property',)

    def computed_property(self, obj):
        # Do anything here
        return value
```

Comment: I found about the same answer while I was poking around, but the bit I was missing was that I needed to add (to ThingieAdmin) computed_property.allow_tags = True.